# ffmpeg loudnorm filter for short media

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to use ffmpeg to determine the overall media volume. I use only one pass :

> ffmpeg -i C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.mp4  -af
>   loudnorm=I=-23:tp=-1:LRA=15:print_format=json -f null -

Out:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\ffmpeg-4.2.1-win64-static\bin>ffmpeg -i C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.mp4  -af loudnorm=I=-23:tp=-1:LRA=15:print_format=json -f null -
ffmpeg version 4.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.1.1 (GCC) 20190807
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2019-01-31T07:52:41.000000Z
    encoder         : Lavf57.57.100
  Duration: 00:00:11.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10459 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], 8918 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-01-31T07:52:41.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: pcm_s16be (twos / 0x736F7774), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-01-31T07:52:41.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-01-31T07:52:41.000000Z
      handler_name    : TimeCodeHandler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> wrapped_avframe (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16be (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, null, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: wrapped_avframe, yuv420p, 720x576 [SAR 16:15 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-01-31T07:52:41.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 wrapped_avframe
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: pcm_s16le, 192000 Hz, stereo, s16, 6144 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-01-31T07:52:41.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 pcm_s16le
[null @ 00000191eeeb7740] Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 0: 274 >= 274
frame=  275 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:11.04 bitrate=N/A speed=15.8x
video:144kB audio:8250kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[Parsed_loudnorm_0 @ 00000191eee03500]
{
        "input_i" : "-22.39",
        "input_tp" : "-11.87",
        "input_lra" : "5.20",
        "input_thresh" : "-32.54",
        "output_i" : "-21.67",
        "output_tp" : "-10.61",
        "output_lra" : "4.90",
        "output_thresh" : "-31.82",
        "normalization_type" : "dynamic",
        "target_offset" : "-1.33"
}
```

On short media (less than 30 seconds), the results of ffmpeg begin to differ significantly from similar checks in Adobe Premier Pro or Orban. 
[When checking this file in Orban](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJPCJ.png).
[When checking this file in Adobe Premier Pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYvuD.png).

Why it happens? And what data is more accurate in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loudnorm filter gives accurate results for the 20-second reference samples included in [EBU Loudness test set](https://tech.ebu.ch/publications/ebu_loudness_test_set). Compare against the meters in other apps.

Comment: Hi Gyan, thanks for your answer. I downloaded the reference signals and on the first three signals (-20, -26, -40) everything is really normal, but in the seq-3341-1-16bit.wav file I came across the following discrepancy in the results. [link](https://yadi.sk/i/R1y0Z5CGi1gL4A)

Comment: As per EBU Tech 3341, the expected response for sample 1 is `M, S, I = −23.0 ±0.1 LUFS` so loudnorm is within tolerance.